# SSH keyfiles not found after changing desktops

Tags: ssh

Recently I changed my desktop from Ubuntu default (Unity) desktop to Kubuntu desktop.
What I cannot understand is why this causes errors with my SSH keyfile configuration.

F.E. there is a "user" user on the "host" computer, where one of my keys (the PK is in ~/.shh locally) added to the authorized keys.
What I want to do is:

```
ssh user@host
```

This worked fine in Unity (if I switch back to Unity still works), but when I log in to Kubuntu desktop, I get prompted for the password.

This works fine on both desktops:

```
ssh user@host -i ~/.ssh/key
```

So I'm guessing the ssh program does not find my keyfiles - but why does the desktop matter, and how can I fix this?

The relevant part from my local .ssh dir (ls -la):

```
drwx------  2 szaboadam szaboadam 4096 okt    7 16:32 .
-rw-------  1 szaboadam szaboadam 1675 okt    7 16:32 key
-rw-r--r--  1 szaboadam szaboadam  415 okt    7 16:32 key.pub
```

And from the server .ssh dir:

```
drwx------ 2 git git 4096 Oct  7 16:33 .                                           
-rwx------ 1 git git  566 Oct  7 16:33 authorized_keys
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.
Thx for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is weird that the command works on Unity, because normally the keys are read from `~/.ssh/id_*` unless they are overridden. You can rename `key` and `key.pub` to `id_*` and `id_*.pub` respectively, where `*` is `dsa`, `rsa`, `ecdsa` or `ed25519`, depending on the type of key (which you can obtain from the public key file).

Alternatively, create `~/.ssh/config` with `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key` in it.

*EDIT:* You can also use `~/.ssh/config` to specify keys on a per-host basis, with things like

```
Host host1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key1

Host host2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key2
```

Comment: Renaming the keys worked. Is there a way to have multiple RSA keys?
F.e for host1 I use key1, for host2 I use key2, etc..., and when I try to connect, linux checks these keys respectively.
Or can I config it so it uses key1 for host1...?

Comment: NVM, I found out that the ~/.ssh/config, that you wrote creates just that

Comment: Yes, you can have several SSH keys. Just use the `-f` flag of `ssh-keygen` to specify the filename you want for your new key. Then you cna use `IdentityFile` in `~/.ssh/config` to specify which keys are used.